# Outlook html email heading color

Tags: css, email, colors, outlook, heading

I am coding HTML template for outlook. There is working `h1` with `color: #8c8c8c;`
However I want to define `h2` or `h3` color, Outlook doesn't let me do it.

For example I try to set color to `#002255;` but it is not working. I have to choose something from W3C palette like `MidnightBlue` and with this syntax it is working.

Could anybody help me?

Comment: Could you post the code where your problem is, please? :)

Comment: which outlook ? 2003 or 2007 or 2010 or 2013? or outloook.com

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it, it is necessary to use the full path to reach the element in css.
So I had to write `table tr td h3` instead of `h3`.

Answer (score 0):

If you change midnightBlue to some color code, like `#002255`, your webpage seems to properly display that color.